# Writing Javascript for client-side class-level validation using PrimeFaces

Tags: javascript, jsf-2, primefaces, bean-validation, java-ee-7

I have a class-level Constraint on my class as below:

```
@NotEqualAccounts
public class FundTransferVO extends SignableVO implements Serializable{
    private String fromAccount;
    private String toAccount;
    //setter,getter
}
```

and my custom Constraint code is:

```
@Target({ElementType.TYPE})
@Retention(RetentionPolicy.RUNTIME)
@Constraint(validatedBy = NotEqualAccountsValidator.class)
@ClientConstraint(resolvedBy=ClientNotEqualAccountsValidator.class)  
public @interface NotEqualAccounts {

    String message() default "{org.javaee7.validation.custom.constraint.NotEqualAccounts}";

    Class<?>[] groups() default {};

    Class<? extends Payload>[] payload() default {};
}
```

I want to have a javaScript for client-side validation of my class using primeFace, I've already written the code below, but it doesn't work

```
PrimeFaces.validator['NotEqualAccounts'] = {               
    MESSAGE_ID: '...',  
    validate: function(element, fundTransferController) {
      if(fundTransferController.fundTransferVO.getToAccount()===fundTransferController.fundTransferVO.getFromAccount()) {   
               msg = '';  
               throw msg;  
       }  
   }  
};
```

fundTransferController is just my controller that my bean(fundTransferVO) is used in it.

Is there a way to validate class-level constraints on client-side using primeFace?

Comment: Which version of JSF-Mojarra/Primefaces are you using?

Comment: jsf2.2 and Primefaces4

Comment: Did you have a look to the PF [client side validation framework](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csvBasic.jsf)?

Comment: Yes,I'm using the field validation in client-side and it's okay. but having a problem using class validation. for field validation in client-side my validate function in script gets a value instead of fundtransferController and simply work on it such as :(this.pattern.test(value)).but in class validation,I want to have access to properties of my value object(fundtransferController ) and I'm not sure how to do that.

Comment: Oh sorry, I forgot to say that I want to use custom class validation in client side.I used this [Client Side Validation - Custom](http://www.primefaces.org/showcase/ui/csvCustom.jsf) as my guide.

Comment: @XtremeBiker, please tell me if there is something wrong about what I'm trying to do.

Comment: So where is your problem, at server or client side? Please clarify it

Comment: @XtremeBiker,at ClientSide with my javascript validate function,it should get my bean and compare to field of it.